# How to make a dictionary with duplicate keys as integers in python with lists

Tags: python, dictionary

**I want to make a dictionary in the format as follow.....**

```
binaries = [1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
positions = [[200,110,10,50],[200,170,10,50],[150,220,50,10],[140,170,10,50],[140,110,10,50],[150,100,50,10],[150,160,50,10]]
```

**here i want the dictionary to look like this**

```
dict = {1:[200,110,10,50], 1:[200,170,10,50],....,0:[150,160,50,10]}

               OR
dict = {1: [[200,110,10,50],[200,170,10,50]...],0:[[150,160,50,10]]}
```

**i mean all the values corresponding to 1 in list positions can be in a single list also.**

Previously i used zip() and dict() to make but it becomes difficult for me because i'm getting confused as it only make dictionary with only 1 and 0 as two keys only.

plzz help me out..

Comment: A dictionary can not have duplicate keys. That's the point of a dictionary.

Comment: @Matthias Yes you are right but i  also  asked to be in the format                             
 dict = {1: [[200,110,10,50],[200,170,10,50]...],0:[[150,160,50,10]]}                                         where all the positions list corresponding to 1 in binaries are in the key 1 and values in the form of a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upfront, the first version is not possible, the entire concept behind a dict (and more generally an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)) is that each key is associated with *one* value.

There are "multimaps" which map one key to multiple values, generally they'll do something like option 2, internally they'll just map keys to lists of values, then provide an interface to retrieve either individual or multiple values.

Anyway as for your second version, it seems relatively straightforward, what's your issue? You just have to zip() the two lists together, and append each new value, ensuring the key is mapped to at least an empty list:

```py
out = {}
for key, value in zip(binaries, positions):
    out.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

If there is no value for `key`, `setdefault` will set it to an empty list. This means we can always append new values without further complication.

Alternatively, `out` could be a `defaultdict` doing that same thing "under the cover".

For a bit more verbosity up-front, it's convenient if you control the entire lifecycle of the mapping (it can have unexpected side-effects otherwise) and would probably be more efficient:

```py
out = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key, value in zip(binaries, positions):
    out[key].append(value)
```

Comment: @Maskinn  Is this collections a module, if yes than what argument in the place of 'list' should i give.

Comment: @Azeem8869786 yes collections is [the collections module from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html), and the `list` builtin is the proper parameter here as that's we want. If it's not working because you have a `list` local variable, you should not have local variables whose names conflict with builtins, so rename it.